# How conservation of momentum is ensured in (Projected) Gauss-Seidel constrain solver

Tags: linear-solver, constrained-optimization, iterative-method, molecular-dynamics

I'm developing molecular dynamics where my time-step is limited by stiffness of the bonds. I trying to get inspiration from game-engines, where they solve similar problem (hard bond constrains). These people think really hard how to get reasonable approximation with low computational effort on GPU, which is exactly what I'm aiming for.

I was reading paper about [Position Based Dynamics](https://matthias-research.github.io/pages/publications/posBasedDyn.pdf) to solve linear (elastic) constrains between bodies in a physics game engine. There is stressed that conservation of linear momentum must be ensured by displacing the bodies (end-points of the constraining bond) by displacement inversely proportional to mass of the points (as shown on Figure 2).

Now I'm reading a different paper [Vivace: a Practical Gauss-Seidel Method for Stable Soft Body Dynamics](https://mfratarcangeli.github.io/publication/sigasia2016/). Here they show that much more efficient algorithm can be implemented using Gauss-Seidel parallelized on GPU using red-black coloring.

How I understand [Gauss-Seidel Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method#Algorithm) in the context of points connected by rigid/elastic sticks can be expressed by following pseudocode:

```py
    repeat until convergence:
        for all points i:
            displacement_i = 0
            for all points j bonded to i by a stick with relaxed lenght L_ij:
               d = position_i - position_j
               l = |d|        # length of the stick
               h = d/|d|      # normalized direction of the stick 
               dl = L_ij - l  # how much the stick needs to be elongated/shortened  
               displacement_i += h * dl
            position_i += displacement_i
```

**What I don't understand:**

when I do update position of the point **i** by Gauss-Seidel (in the outer for loop), it moves the point i asymmetrically to satisfy the constrain, while it does not move the neighboring points to which it is connected (i.e. it does not exert the **recoil** according to [3rd Newton Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Third_law)). Therefore the result will depend very much on the order in which I update the point positions.

If I choose the order badly, it can easily happen that I displace the heavy points a lot and displace a light points a little. For example consider that I have just 2 points connected by one stick (`mass_1 >> mass_2`). According to the algorithm above I solve the constrain in 1 step by displacing `point_1` so that it is exactly at distance `l=L_12` from `point_2`. However such solution would be unphysical because it will move the heavy point and not move the light point. The center of mass will move a lot, and conservation of the linear momentum will be violated.